# ComponentWillMount trigger not stop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactjs-flux

Firstly I'm newbie on React and this is my first project.

I'm creating a basically blog app, my app class like below:

```
var App = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            posts: Store.getPosts(),
            newPost: {
                headerText: '',
                bodyText: ''
            }
        };
    },

    componentWillMount: function () {
        console.info("App component will mount")
        Store.addChangeListener(this.changeState);
    },

    componentWillUnmount: function () {
        Store.removeChangeListener(this.changeState);
    },

    componentDidMount: function() {
        console.info("App component mounted.")
        Store.removeChangeListener(this.changeState);
    } ,

    changeState: function () {
        this.setState({
            posts: Store.getPosts()
        });
    },
```

When my app run `componentWillMount` method triggered and call `this.changeState` method and it call `Store.getPosts()` method from flux store.

But this thing don't stop. Continuously call xhr requests from server. My network console like this when app started.

[image]

I tried add `componentDidMount` for solve this but in this case posts don't received from server when app started.

I want just one time load all posts when app started and then run when I call `setState` method.

Comment: does your Store.getPosts() call the API ? if yes then you still not clear with flux

Comment: Yes :( Like I said above, I'm newbie on react. But is it normally called continiously getStores if even without API call?

Comment: When my app run componentWillMount method triggered and call this.changeState method and it call Store.getPosts() method from flux store it's not true when your component load at that time your getInitialState called and it will fetch the data

Comment: do one thing upload your code somewhere in dropbox and let me check don't include node_module in it

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/q8bunihkfdj5lb6/ss-blog.rar?dl=0

Comment: at my machine it's not call again and again it's just call one single time

Comment: codes are which sent to you running on here http://188.226.173.227:3000, but calling continuously

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99121/discussion-between-dhaval-patel-and-furkan-basaran).

Comment: I hope you got your solution if yes then accept my answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are Call again and again so your store should have method like

```
 var _post={};
  getDataonly:function()
    {
      return _post;
    },
```

you have to create a function which can handle the state change and call that function when it's required

```
function setpostState()
{
 return
  {
   post:Store.getPost()
 }
}
```

and you have to set this variable when you got the data from api like

```
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url : config.serviceURL + "/posts"
  })
      .then(function successCallback(res) {
        if(!res.error) {
          that.posts = res.data;
          _post=res.data;
          that.emitChange();
        } else console.error(res.message);
      })
```

and your main.js changeState method should be

```
  changeState: function () {
    this.setState(setpostState());
},
```

Comment: As I comment below, I do not believe it is the correct approach to invoke in the changeState some specific API of the store. Since he is learning we should help him to follo wbest practices and not workarounds.

Comment: @ungarida:yes it's not a correct approach I am going to change my answer but  above mentioned changes is only for OP :)  because he has implemented application with same structure

Answer (score 2):

what is suspicious is the **changeState** function. What flux implementation are you using? Usually should look like:

```
   changeState: function (state) {
    this.setState(state);
   }
```

Usually you interact with stores throw actions and listening to store changes without direct invocation of any method.

Comment: yes op has directly call the API without using action and that is not a good practice with flux